# How to uninstall Nagios and NRPE

Tags: nagios

Can you tell me how can i uninstall nagios and NRPE.
I have tried this command to uninstall NRPE:

```
sudo apt-get remove nagios-nrpe-server
```

but when I execute this command it's display to me the version of Nrpe installed

```
./check_nrpe -H localhost
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps in given order.

```
 1. sudo apt-get remove nagios-nrpe-server
 2. sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nagios-nrpe-server
 3. sudo apt-get purge nagios-nrpe-server
 4. sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nagios-nrpe-server
```

Reboot your machine ,hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove all the `nagios` packages by:

```
sudo apt-get remove nagios*
```